# Django organization app & models

Tags: python, django

I'm beginner in `python` and `django` (but i have 5 years experience in `php`, with a enterprise framework).
I am making a web site which has two clearly separated front office.
When you visit the home page you have to choose which part of the site you want.
So I will to make two app like this :

```
website
  |context.py
  |settings.py
  |etc.
      |front1
        |models.py
        |view.py
        |urls.py
        |etc.
      |front2
        |models.py
        |view.py
        |urls.py
        |etc.
```

My problem is that I need a model [customer] who will used by the two apps.
Where do I have to put it ?
I have tried to add a `models.py` in website's directory but `django` ignores it.
Is this possible to do? Maybe two apps for that is not a good idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Apps in Django are not UI units, but rather logical units. So if you have a Customer model that has its own related views and APIs, make a customer app and put the model there. You can have your separate UI frontends in different templates, but unless they operate on separate different entities (models) there is no reason to put them into separate apps. Either way, make a customer app and in your frontend views you can do

```
from customer.models import Customer
```

and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Ok my organization is bad, thanks for helping, i will change that.
One more question, is this possible to put models in another file than model.py and how to tell that to django (for django use it for update database for example)

Comment: I am not sure if Django actually expects models to be in a file called models, but the convention for this is strong. But since this is python, you can define your models elsewhere and import them into models.py if you want. Also, this might help
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package